# Degeneracy of $\left|\pm k\right\rangle $: because of reflection symmetry or time reversal symmetry?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, symmetry

Consider a free particle in one dimension. The Hamiltonian is

$$ H = p^2/2m .  $$

It is well known that the momentum states $\left|\pm  k \right\rangle $ are degenerate.

The problem is, are they degenerate because of the reflection symmetry or the time reversal symmetry?

Comment: Well, it depends on the spin of the particle. In general, inversion will not flip the spin, but time reversal will. Therefore +k;up will be mapped to -k;down under time reversal but +k;up will be mapped to -k;up under inversion.

Comment: @Xcheckr   But suppose there is no spin.

Answer (score 2):

In general (i.e. ignoring coincidental degeneracy), eigenvalues of Hamiltonian are degenerate if there exist two operators which commute with Hamiltonian (so their corresponding observable is conserved), but which don't commute with each other.

A free particle has two non-commuting conserved quantities: parity and momentum. Eigenfunctions of the former are standing waves (sines and cosines), while eigenfunctions of the latter are running waves (complex exponentials). Both types of eigenfunctions can be chosen with given energy, and it's this freedom what gives you degeneracy.

As a contrast, a particle in the box has reflection symmetry (so parity is conserved), but its energies are all non-degenerate, because there's no such other conserved quantity as momentum.